# How to modify LVM Volume Group when I don't have all the drives connected

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm

Prior to upgrading some of my hardware I had 4 drives used just as storage. Now I'm trying to mount the drives as an LVM but I don't have enough slots to connect all the drives at once now b/c they use an outdated type of cable. I can connect three of the four. So, can I somehow move these to a new group, or remove the missing drive from the existing group?

The error is:

Couldn't read all logical volumes for volume group VolGroup.
Couldn't find device with uuid 'yQtrVB-5jCk-vF10-05c2-AcDL-GNn1-ivdxxh'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the '-P', or '--partial' option. From the lvm manpage:

```
       -P | --partial
              When set, the tools will do their best to provide access to vol‐
              ume groups that are only partially available.
```

Comment: Awesome! OK, 
But when I do 'lvs' after that is only shows a boot and swap partition in the volumes. I'm expecting something like 'LogVol00'. Ideas?

Comment: It still needs to have access to the disks which make up the LV's in order to access them. If you have any LV's which span all 4 PV's, then you're still not going to be able to access them.

Comment: THey were not in a raid or anything -- they were their own inddividual drives with individual data.

Comment: Yes, but a LV can be on more than one PV. If you have 2 500Gb drives, and 3 300Gb filesystems, you might have 300Gb on drive 1 for FS1, 200 on drive 1 for FS2, 100 on drive 2 for FS2, and 300 on drive 2 for FS3. Then FS1 will be accessible if you have drive 1 connected, FS3 if you have drive 2 connected, but FS2 needs to have both drives connected, because the data is on both drives.

I don't have multiple PV's on my system here, but I belive that "pvdisplay -m" will tell which devices each lv is on, and you can then deduce which drives need to be installed to access that filesystem.